# Calculation between two tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select

I have two tables A and B:
Table A

```
Txn_amt2    rrn     Pan     Stan    Msg_type
22000       7123344 556677  442233  0200
22000       7123344 556677  442233  0200
22000       7123344 556677  442233  0200
22000       7123344 556677  442233  0200
35200       7178866 223344  989898  0200
67000       7199933 667733  343433  0200
```

Table B

```
Txn_amt1    rrn     Pan     Stan    Msg_type
89000       7123344 556677  442233  0220
35400       7178866 223344  989898  0220
67100       7199933 667733  343433  0220
```

I need to find the difference of txn_amt1 with txn_amt2 or the difference of sum(txn_amt2)-txn_amt1 depending on the case
There are two cases:
1.  When there are values equal with each other (like in table a 22000 repeated 4 times) on the column txn_amt2 in table A. I should sum this values where rrn,pan,stan of table A are equal for the values repeated and after that I have to subtract the sum with  Txn_amt1 of table B where rrn,pan,stan are equal for the two tables.
2.  When txn_amt2 doesn’t repeat herself on which means that this row exist only one time in table A I have to subtract txn_amt1 with txn_amt2 where rrn,pan,stan of the two tables are equal.

This is the result that I should expect after the query was executed 
diff(txn_amt1 - txn_amt2 or sum(txn_amt2)-txn_amt1)

```
1000
200
100
```

I need a function in SQL or query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum the tableA and B and then join. If TableB no duplicated rows, no need sum:

```
SELECT a.rrn, a.Pan, a.Stan, a.Msg_type, 
  sum(ifnull(b.amt1, 0) - ifnull(a.amt2, 0)) AS amt_diff
FROM (
  SELECT rrn,Pan Stan,Msg_type,sum(Txn_amt2) AS amt2
  FROM tableA GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
) AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT rrn,Pan Stan,Msg_type,sum(Txn_amt1) AS amt1
  FROM tableB GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
) AS b ON a.rrn = b.rrn AND a.Stan = b.Stan AND a.Msg_type = b.Msg_type
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I edit the query and this is how should be: SELECT a.rrn, a.Pan, a.Stan,
  sum(ifnull(b.amt1, 0) - ifnull(a.amt2, 0)) AS amt_diff
FROM (
  SELECT rrn,Pan,Stan,sum(Txn_amt2) AS amt2
  FROM a GROUP BY 1,2,3
) AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT rrn,Pan,Stan,sum(Txn_amt1) AS amt1
  FROM b GROUP BY 1,2,3
) AS b ON a.rrn = b.rrn AND a.Stan = b.Stan
GROUP BY 1,2,3